# Multi-threading list pattern advice

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, design-patterns, asynchronous

I have made an application which also contains a folder/file scanner. I'm coming across a problem with the threading structure.

How it works:
For each folder/file it finds it starts a thread. There is a function inside each thread that uses a list to check if a similar item has been found so that it can add to the existing item. If it's not found it will add the item to the earlier mentioned list. The threads are executed parallel (async).

Problem:
Because it's async it will sometimes fail on the listcheck. This is caused because there is a time period between the check and adding to the list. Something that can happen is that the check returns that there is not a similar item, while there certainly is. This will result in the same item occurring in the list.

I have also made it that threads wait on each other. I really like the effect this gives it on the frontend. (items nicely adding to the list real time). But this takes way to long for a lot of folders/files.

Now I'm thinking of making a mix between the functions, but i would really like to see a combination of the speed of async threads and the safety of waiting on each thread.

Anybody any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should lock the entire code part that checks the list and adds a value.

Something like this:

```
private void YourThreadMethod(object state)
{
    // long taking operation

    lock (dictionary)
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(yourItemKey))
        {
            // construct object, long taking operation

            dictionary.Add(yourItemKey, createdObject);
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, every thread will have to wait until the `list` is free to use. If you want a more advanced solution, you could read into the [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which gives a more fine grained solution.

Comment: Why not `ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte>`?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: Because that doesn't prevent the checking with delayed adding problem.

Comment: You are just constructing a lock around a non-atomic operation to make it "atomic" - what's the difference to `TryAdd`? Am I missing something - *This will result in the same item occurring in the list.* which is exactly the reason for `TryAdd`...??

Comment: Well, that could be useful if the construction of the object doesn't take too long so you could prepare it. I thought it would take some time to enumerate the directory info.

Comment: I am still not getting your demur :) ... The object needs to be constructed anyway to get the hash to store (`yourItemKey`) - additionally I would simply store a plain representation of an object instead of a full reference (you know, to avoid all the needed disposal and stuff...) as the key, and using a `byte` for the value is just as a marker.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I have looked at the problem again and found a possible solution. The problem was not related to the use of async lists (i was already using a custom made DispatchingObservableCollection) The solution is making the time period between the check and the add as short as possible. Now it's fast and the items are nicely added. But thanks for all the fast reactions! EDIT: ah i'm sorry. I did indeed implement your locking mechanism and now i see when i remove this it isn't working xD so it's a combination of the locking mechanism and the reduced time period!!!!!

Comment: @RolandMakkelie that's hence the non-atomic nature of checking and adding. Only atomic (or sealed/non-reorderable cpu-instructions like the ones from `Interlocked`) are guaranteed to be free from any race-condition. As an addition: You can even go for `dictionary[key] = value` if you do not have any special behaviour on existance, to provide the latest value to be always persisted (except in multi-core environments, where 2 threads can be executed in real parallel)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair thanks for the explanation. It's not really about the latest value. I will give an example with the project i'm doing. The scanner is about a movie/serie scanner. In the beginning of a thread it's not known if it's about a serie or movie. On the end of the thread the movie/serie is added to the list. In the middle of the thread there is a check that searches the list to check if the serie already exists. If so: add it as an episode to the existing serie. I think with the locking mechanism it is going to work, but first I need to simplify the code.

Answer (score 2):

The most sleekest approach is the usage of a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte>` when `yourItemKey` is type of `string` ([otherwise adapt `TKey` and use a proper `IEqualityComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287107.aspx) or [implement IEquatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)):

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte> _list = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte>();
private void Foo(object state)
{
  // looong operation
  this._list.TryAdd(yourItemKey, 0);
}
public void Bar()
{
  // this is how to query the content
  this._list.Keys...;
}
```

The trick behind that is to not use a too complex object as the key, which may need disposal or has external references (I'd prefer any string representation), and a small type for the value, which just acts as a marker.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using one of the [thread safe collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in C#. For your case something like a `ConcurrentBag` will be more efficient than using a lock.

In case there is a time delay between checking and adding, you can use `ConcurrentDictionary`. It has a [TryAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267291(v=vs.110).aspx) method which will return `false` if an item  with the same key is already in the dictionary.

Comment: That isn't a solution when there is time between checking and adding.

Comment: True, you can do that with `ConcurrentDictionary` though, it does the check and add in one atomic operation.

Comment: @NedStoyanov I wouldn't call that *atomic* per se, as it is not one operation. Internally a locking mechanism is used to ensure no interference. The lock acquisition is an atomic operation indeed (depending on the processor), but `TryAdd` is *just* thread-safe :)